# Java - ResultSet getString() Inconsistency

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have MySQL Stored Procedure that returns a String using **GROUP_CONCAT** with around *1200* - *1300* characters. However, when the packet returned in my Java code, the length is reduced to *1023/1024*.

I tried to increase the MySQL's **max_allowed_packet** to *524288000* and **group_concat_max_len** to *1000000000* but no luck.

Any idea regarding this matter?

Comment: You haven't posted anything that could help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change parameter `group_concat_max_len` for overcoming this limitation.
For that you can use following command

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 100000;
```

Please note that this change is session specific ie... temporary. So you have to execute above before your `group_concat` query.

For your information default value of group_concat_max_len is 1024.

**Additional Information**

You can also set using following query

```
set global group_concat_max_len = 100000;
```

Even if you used that, if you restart mysql you will miss that. If you want to make changes permanent please use following

In mysql configuration file, under `[mysqld]` add

`group_concat_max_len=100000`
Then do a restart.

Comment: Hi Fathah. Thanks for your help. I did change the group_concat_max_len globally but it didn't help. I tried to set the session variable explicitly before executing the query and it did work. I'm satisfied with the result. I'm thinking if there's a solution that will not require me to set the length variable explicitly?

Comment: @MichaelArdan - answer modified, please check newly added part